# Difference between two directories

Tags: bash, unix, directory, diff, traversal

below is the question:
Suppose in DirA I have these files:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
```

and in DirB I have below files:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

Now If i Have to make a script which tells me the diffrence between the two directorie (in this case it is file4 missing in dirB) and so also copies the file in DirB, what would be the commands?

Answer (score 7):

This will show a brief summary of the differences:

```
diff -rq dir1 dir2
```

It will tell if a file exists in only one of the directories, or if a file exists in both directories with different content it will tell that they are different. In your example it would go something like:

```
$ diff -rq dir1 dir2
Only in dir1: file4
```

If you want to see more details, drop the `-q` flag (it stands for "quiet").

Comment: @user3403309 Welcome to StackOverflow. You can thank by marking the answer correct. You can do so by clicking the tick mark next to the answer.